# How can I show a confirmation thickbox with the selection after user presses submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, modal-dialog

How can I show a confirmation modal dialog with the information from the form so that user can confirm what they selected in the form and it submits only if the user says so?

```
confirm.$("#submit-button").click( function(){
    if (validator.form()==true) {
        tb_show("Countdown", "are_you_sure.html?height=100&width=200&modal=true", "");
    //some check here maybe?    
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: by not doing so and by realizing that by clicking the button, they mean they want to do it.

Answer (score 0):

tb_show can display a hidden DIV, so perhaps the best way is to fill that div with the stuff you want the user to confirm and then simply show that. The DIV could hold a YES button that when clicked performs the actual submit

```
<script>
$('#confirmDiv').html("Are you sure you want to...");
tb_show("Countdown", "#TB_inline?height=100&width=200&inlineId=confirmDiv");
...

<body>
...
<div id='confirmDiv' style='display:none'></div>
```